# Could this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Sorry about the vague title. I couldn't come up with anything better that describes the question. Anyway …

I'm planning an upcoming trip, most of which will be by plane due to how far I'm travelling. However, for the last leg of the trip I have the option of being driven by someone I know from the airport to my final destination, or taking the bus. However, the problem is that the bus leaves in the morning, and I arrive at the airport late at night. As such, I need to make the choice, do I stay at a hotel near the airport which I could walk to and then take the bus in the morning, or have the person drive me to my destination at night time? The distance is significant enough for it to take two to three hours depending on traffic.

There are many factors I have to consider when making this choice, but what I would like to know is which of these options is more sustainable. However, is this a question that could be "stackable", i.e., on-topic for the Sustainability Stack Exchange given how many variables there are? If yes, should I be specific about my circumstances, or try to make it a generic question? Could it even be answered in a non-specific fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this question could be a good fit. Check out the [transport](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport) [tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transport) -- there are a few good questions along these lines:

- [What is the most climate friendly way to travel from Copenhagen to Atlanta?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12144/3379)
- [How can I make my family understand my CO2-emissions-related hesitation to fly in order to spend time with them?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6203/3379)
- [Is flying more sustainable than taking the train?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6130/3379)

In general, I'd say to focus your question on the problem you're trying to solve -- how to determine whether driving or getting a hotel and taking the bus has a lower carbon footprint.